# NPM standard-version patch version problem

Tags: javascript, git, npm, semantic-versioning, conventional-commits

I'm trying to use [standard-version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard-version) in my javascript project. I added the `release` script to my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "release": "standard-version"
}
```

My problem is that I added a commit to my git repo with the following message:

```
feat: test
```

I run `npm run release` and it increased the patch version of the project.

So my initial version was `0.2.1` (tag: v0.2.1), and it generated `0.2.2` with this commit message

```
chore(release): 0.2.2
```

Why didn't it increase the minor version?

Comment: Are there different rules for versions beginning with major version `0`?

Comment: semver is very loose when the major version begins with 0.  Once you release 1.0.0, then the rules should apply.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I think it would be very useful to specify explicitly that it’s either x.y.z, 0.x.y, or 0.0.x, and x is semver-major, y semver-minor, z semver-patch (this is how the npm ecosystem tends to treat it)
> — [ljharb](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/333#issuecomment-626195156)

Caret `^` match [Minor releases](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning#:%7E:text=compatible%20new%20features-,Minor%20release,-Increment%20the%20middle) (It is also the default value for `save-prefix` in npm config), but it work different for *0.0.X*, *0.X.X* and *X.X.X*

So, for example *^0.0.1* will work like this

```
[✓] 0.0.1
[x] 0.0.2
[x] 0.0.3
[x] 0.1.0
```

for *^0.1.0* will work like this

```
[✓] 0.1.0
[✓] 0.1.1
[✓] 0.1.2
[x] 0.2.0
[x] 0.2.1
[x] 0.3.0
```

and for *^1.0.0* like normal:

```
[✓] 1.0.0
[✓] 1.0.1
[✓] 1.1.0
[✓] 1.2.1
[x] 2.0.0
```

Tilde `~` match [Patch releases](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning#:%7E:text=compatible%20bug%20fixes-,Patch%20release,-Increment%20the%20third), doesn't have exceptions in it behavior for *0.0.X*, *0.X.X* and *X.X.X* (*Perhaps because it is not a default value in npm config, idk really*). It has the same behavior everywhere:

*~0.0.1*

```
[✓] 0.0.1
[✓] 0.0.2
[✓] 0.0.3
[x] 0.1.0
```

*~0.1.0*

```
[✓] 0.1.0
[✓] 0.1.1
[✓] 0.1.2
[x] 0.2.0
[x] 0.2.1
[x] 0.3.0
```

*~1.0.0*

```
[✓] 1.0.0
[✓] 1.0.1
[x] 1.1.0
[x] 1.2.1
[x] 2.0.0
```

You can check the behavior [here](https://semver.npmjs.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Until you publish your first release, the bumping of the package.json is going to be that way. In the package documentation, it is better explained

https://github.com/conventional-changelog/standard-version#first-release

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).